# Converting a string to a class name

Tags: c#, .net

I have a string variable that represents the name of a custom class. Example:

```
string s = "Customer";
```

I will need to create an arraylist of customers. So, the syntax needed is:

```
List<Customer> cust = new ..
```

How do I convert the string s to be able to create this arraylist on runtime?

Comment: John, there is no generic implementation of the ArrayList class in the .NET framework. Bob, this is out of scope for the question, but if you're programming in C# 2.0+, you should substitute the ArrayList for something generic.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Well, for one thing `ArrayList` isn't generic... did you mean `List<Customer>`?

You can use `Type.GetType(string)` to get the `Type` object associated with a type by its name. If the assembly isn't either mscorlib or the currently executing type, you'll need to include the assembly name. Either way you'll need the namespace too.

Are you sure you really need a generic type? Generics mostly provide *compile-time* type safety, which clearly you won't have much of if you're finding the type at execution time. You *may* find it useful though...

```
Type elementType = Type.GetType("FullyQualifiedName.Of.Customer");
Type listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(new Type[] { elementType });

object list = Activator.CreateInstance(listType);
```

If you need to *do* anything with that list, you may well need to do more generic reflection though... e.g. to call a generic method.

Answer (score 29):

This is a reflection question.  You need to find the type then instantiate an instance of it, something like this:

```
Type hai = Type.GetType(classString,true);
Object o = (Activator.CreateInstance(hai));  //Or you could cast here if you already knew the type somehow
```

or, CreateInstance(assemblyName, className)

You will need to watch out for namespace/type clashes though, but that will do the trick for a simple scenario.

Also, wrap that in a try/catch!  Activator.CreateInstance is scary!