# create a generic class for the type name

Tags: c#, generics

there is a class

```
public class Repository <TKey, TEntity>
{
    public ICollection<TEntity> Get()
    {
        using (var session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
        {
            if (typeof(TEntity).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IActualizable)))
                return session.CreateCriteria(typeof(TEntity)).Add(Restrictions.Lt("ActiveTo", DBService.GetServerTime())).List<TEntity>();

            return session.CreateCriteria(typeof(TEntity)).List<TEntity>();
        }
    }
}
```

how to create it, knowing only the name of TEntity?

Example:

class Game
{
}

string nameEntity = "Game";

var repository = new Repository< long, **???** >();

Comment: check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/493490/converting-a-string-to-a-class-name

Comment: Type type = Type.GetType(entityName);
Type entity = typeof(DBCloud.Repositories.Repository<>).MakeGenericType(new Type[] { type });
var rep = Activator.CreateInstance(entity);

Error 1 Using the generic type 'Repository<TKey,TEntity>' requires 2 type arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's three parts to this:

- getting the `Type` from the string `"Game"`
- creating the generic instance
- doing something useful with it

The first is *relatively* easy, assuming you know a bit more - for example, that `Game` is in a particular assembly and namespace. If you know some *fixed* type in that assembly, you could use:

```
Type type = typeof(SomeKnownType).Assembly
      .GetType("The.Namespace." + nameEntity);
```

(and check it doesn't return `null`)

Then we need to create the generic type:

```
object repo = Activator.CreateInstance(
      typeof(Repository<,>).MakeGenericType(new[] {typeof(long), type}));
```

however, note that this is `object`. It would be more convenient if there was a non-generic interface or base-class that you could use for `Repository<,>` - I would put *serious* though into adding one!

To *use* that, the easiest approach here will be `dynamic`:

```
dynamic dynamicRepo = repo;
IList entities = dynamicRepo.Get();
```

and use the non-generic `IList` API. If `dynamic` isn't an option, you'd have to use reflection.

Alternatively, adding a non-generic API would make this trivial:

```
interface IRepository {
    IList Get();
}
public class Repository <TKey, TEntity> : IRepository {
    IList IRepository.Get() {
        return Get();
    }
    // your existing code here
}
```

then it is just:

```
var repo = (IRepository)Activator.CreateInstance(
      typeof(Repository<,>).MakeGenericType(new[] {typeof(long), type}));
IList entities = repo.Get();
```

Note: depending on the data, `IList` might not work - you might need to drop to the non-generic `IEnumerable` instead.

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<TEntity>' to 'System.Collections.IList'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)