# Create an instance of a class according to a string

Tags: c#, class

I have 12 classes in my project like this:

```
class class1
{

}

class class2
{

}
```

in another class I have a method that I want to create an instance of `class1` or `class2`
according to a string:

```
public void MyMethod(string s)
{
//I want to create an instance of class1 if s=="class1" or class2 if s=="class2"
}
```

How I can do this?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247598/c-sharp-instantiate-class-from-string

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/493490/converting-a-string-to-a-class-name

Comment: Please look at Factory Methods and the Factory Design Pattern as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a work around try this hope it will work.

First you need to pass class actual name in string, e.g if you have a class `ClassA` then Pass `ClassA` to this one it will create an instance of the class.

```
private object MyMethod(string className)
{
    var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

    var type = assembly.GetTypes()
    .First(t => t.Name == className);

    return Activator.CreateInstance(type);
}
```

Comment: In this case I can't access to Methods of class because it is an object.

Comment: you got it wrong this is not object it's returning object of your desired class.

Comment: i declared this method as static that's why you wouldn't be able to access it from non-static types. Now i changed it to non-static method now it will become available to your intelli-sense.