# ParseEnum from string when enum type is also named like string

Tags: c#, string, enums

```
public static T ParseEnum<T>(string value)
        {
            return (T) Enum.Parse(typeof (T), value, true);
        }
```

I can simply do:

```
var parsed = EnumUtils.ParseFromString<Gender>("Man");
```

but sometimes I get type of enum as string. Can i Convert string to enum type and use it in my EnumUtils.

I trid like:

```
Type enumType = Type.GetType(Gender,true);
Object o = (Activator.CreateInstance(enumType)); 

var parsed = EnumUtils.ParseFromString<enumType>("Man");
```

but not working. `enumType` is not recognozed in generic way.

I also know for this site:
[Converting a string to a class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493490/converting-a-string-to-a-class-name)
and
[How do I use reflection to call a generic method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-generic-method)

but does not help me, because I don't know the type of Enum it is not always Gender, can be 100 other enums. I know the name of enum as string and not as type.

Answer (score 2):

No you can't use a generic method like that.  You have have to have the generic type at compile time.

There's no need for you to call the your `EnumUtils.ParseFromString()` method.  Just call `Enum.Parse()` directly.

```
String typeNameString;
 ...
Type enumType = Type.GetType(typeNameString,true);
Object parsed =  Enum.Parse(enumType, value, true)
```

Answer (score 1):

The most *generic* way I can think of would be to return an `Enum` type from your parse method:

```
enum MyEnum
{
    Value1
}

Type enumType = typeof(MyEnum);
string enumString = "Value1";
Enum enumValue = enumString.ToEnum(enumType);
```

additionaly you can turn your parse method into an extension:

```
public static Enum ToEnum(this string value, Type enumType)
{
    return (Enum)Enum.Parse(enumType, value, true);
}
```