# How do I create an instance from a string in C#?

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm reading information from an XML which contains the type of an object that I need to instantiate along with it's constructor parameters.

The object type is actually in another project, within a sibling namespace. (I need to create a Company.Project2.Type within Company.Project1 class.)

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223952/c-create-an-instance-of-a-class-from-a-string), but it doesn't handle the constructor parameters or the fact that it's in another namespace.

How can I do this?

**Edit:** The assembly name and default namespace wasn't set correctly in the project properties.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

- You need to specify the full type name to [`Type.GetType()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx), including namespace, e.g. "Company.Project2.Type"
- If the type isn't in the same assembly (or mscorlib), you need to give the assembly name too, including version information if it's strongly typed. For example, for a non-strongly typed assembly `Company.Project2.dll`, you might specify "Company.Project2.Type, Company.Project2".
- To call a constructor with parameters you can call [`Activator.CreateInstance(Type, Object[])`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcxyzt4d.aspx) or get the exact constructor you want with [`Type.GetConstructor()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getconstructor.aspx) and then call [`ConstructorInfo.Invoke()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.constructorinfo.invoke.aspx).

If that doesn't help, please give more information.

Comment: Type.GetType() doesn't seem to find the type with the string I give it. The class Prop is defined in the Reaver.GamePlay namespace, but the returned type is null.

Comment: I've also tried "Reaver.GamePlay.Prop, Reaver.GamePlay" to no avail.

Comment: @Ben: What assembly is it in? Is the assembly strongly typed?

Comment: @JonSkeet I believe it is impossible to use this code to generates String object - since it doesnt have a constructor.(IMHO) .... Can you  please provide an alternative for string ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: There are various constructors for `string`. Have a look at MSDN. But in the case of string, it would probably be worth special-casing to just use the string data directly.

Comment: @JonSkeet I meant Default CTOR. ( sorry for not mention it)

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Right, there's no parameterless constructor. But this question states: "I'm reading information from an XML which contains the type of an object that I need to instantiate along with it's constructor parameters."

Answer (score 3):

If you want to create a type dynamically at run time, Activator.CreateInstance Method will do  it for you.  If you issue is with the type having a constructor with parameters, this overload will do this.
For example,
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcxyzt4d.aspx

I advise looking through the overloads for the best match.

The namespace issue should be not be relavant - as long as the dll is in the bin directory or the GAC you should be OK. The rules may change if the assembly is Strongly named though.

Could you provide a code snippiet of the code that is not working (using the method you linked to)? This + the errors you are seeing will be very helpful!
[update]
Quick sample using the Activator.CreateInstance that handles Constructors w/ paramaters.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BaseProduct b =(BaseProduct)System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("ConsoleApplication1.Product")
                ,new object[]{typeof(string)}, 
                new object[]{"123"}
            );
            //Activator..::.CreateInstance Method (Type, array<Object>[]()[], array<Object>[]()[])
        }
    }
    public class Product: BaseProduct{
        public  Product(string id) { 

        }
        public string Id {get;set;}


   }

    public abstract class BaseProduct {
        abstract public string Id { get; set; }
    }
}
```