# Instantiate a class from its textual name

Tags: c#, string, class, instantiation

Don't ask me why but I need to do the following:

```
string ClassName = "SomeClassName";  
object o = MagicallyCreateInstance("SomeClassName");
```

I want to know how many ways there are to do this is and which approach to use in which scenario.

Examples:

- `Activator.CreateInstance`
- `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.CreateInstance("")`
- Any other suggestions would be appreciated

This question is not meant to be an open ended discussion because I am sure there are only so many ways this can be achieved.

Comment: A possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648160/how-do-i-create-an-instance-from-a-string-in-c

Comment: Hmm, what are the odds that you can guess its namespace name correctly?  And the assembly it comes from?

Comment: Is the assembly the type is in already loaded or not?  If this happens to be something around plugins, you might check out MEF

Comment: Also, does the class have a no-args ctor? (Specifically, can that be assumed)

Comment: Actually, these class namespace is known and the classes exist in the same assembly in which I need to do this.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Here's what the method may look like:

```
private static object MagicallyCreateInstance(string className)
{
    var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

    var type = assembly.GetTypes()
        .First(t => t.Name == className);

    return Activator.CreateInstance(type);
}
```

The code above assumes that:

- you are looking for a class that is in the currently executing assembly (this can be adjusted - just change `assembly` to whatever you need)
- there is exactly one class with the name you are looking for in that assembly
- the class has a default constructor

**Update:**

Here's how to get all the classes that derive from a given class (and are defined in the same assembly):

```
private static IEnumerable<Type> GetDerivedTypesFor(Type baseType)
{
    var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

    return assembly.GetTypes()
        .Where(baseType.IsAssignableFrom)
        .Where(t => baseType != t);
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks. I also need to enumerate all classes that derive this class we just created. I'm assuming `assembly.GetTypes` would allow that.

Comment: @RaheelKhan I have added a code sample for getting the derived classes defined in the same assembly.

Comment: After we got the class, can we call the method inside?

Comment: @andrefadila Yes. Be aware though that `Activator.CreateInstance` [returns an `object`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83(v=vs.110).aspx) and you may need to cast it first.

Comment: Thanks for response @w0lf. So, we must cast it first. Is there any solution without cast?

Comment: You could also call the method via reflection. (This is pretty hacky)

Comment: Or you could cast the object not to its exact type, but to an interface that defines that method.

Comment: What if the class I want to instantiate is not in the current assembly but lies in the same solution?

Answer (score 21):

```
Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("SomeNamespace.SomeClassName"));
```

or

```
Activator.CreateInstance(null, "SomeNamespace.SomeClassName").Unwrap();
```

There are also overloads where you can specify constructor arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Use this way to use the class name without the fully qualified namespace:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CreateInstance("myclass");
```