# How can I instantiate an object with Class.forName and convert it to the right type?

Tags: java, class

I have read this article : 
[Construct Object using class name](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=113)
and now I know how to do this:

```
MySuperClass mClass = new MySuperClass();
```

<=>

```
Class<?> MyClass = Class.forName("MySuperClass");
MySuperClass mClass = MyClass.newInstance();
```

They are equivalent, right?

But now there is a problem. The user clicks on the List of class names and I should create an object of that class at runtime. Say these classes are all subclasses of `MySuperClass`. So could anyone please tell me how I can do this with `Class.forName`?

```
MySuperClass mClass = new ...(); // The subclass name in place of "..." can be determined at runtime.
```

Or this?

```
... mClass = new ...(); // The subclass name in place of "..." can be determined at runtime.
```

Comment: Just a side question - Are you sure you want it saved as a MySuperClass? If you do so, the individual methods available in the subclasses won't be available to you through mClass.

Comment: @Bucco I changed my question description, it does not have to be MySuperClass. But still I do not know how to convert it at runtime. Could you please help me?

Comment: Ah, I now realize the implications of your question. It is impossible to do what I was asking of you (the ... mClass = new ...();) or atleast impossible to the best of my abilities. I'll post the answer to the MySupperClass part. Interesting question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had the right idea going with the whole Class.forName thing.

For the `MySuperClass mClass = new ...();` code, lets assume that you have the name stored in a String, and let us call it `className`.

```
Class<?> subClass = Class.forName(className);
MySuperClass mClass = (MySuperClass) subClass.newInstance();
```

Note that className can also have packages as shown in [Is there a way to instantiate a class by name in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886266/is-there-a-way-to-instantiate-a-class-by-name-in-java)

As you can see, the code is very similar to what you had before, except you just had to cast the subclass to the super class. Alternatively, you could set it as an Object, but with limited functionality.

Comment: Thank you for the warning on packages. ^^

Comment: Alternative option: `subclass.asSubclass(MySuperClass.class).newInstance()`, which wouldn't require casting.

Answer (score 0):

write a static block in your MyClass

now when you load the class by `class.forName()` static block is executed

so keep your object creation inside the static block

Answer (score 0):

You can use issAssignableFrom method to determine the sublcass and then initiaze the object.

```
public void checkSubClassOfSuperClass(Class subClas){   

     if (subClas != SuperClass.class && SuperClass.class.isAssignableFrom(subClas)) {
         // initialize and assign operation
     }
}
```