# How to convert a string to class type in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I want to convert this string into `AppDatabase` type, I tried this `Class.forName()` but this is not working properly.

```
val str = "com.crypto.wallet.data.AppDatabase_Impl@14731a42"
```

my class path is "**com.crypto.wallet.data.AppDatabase**"

I am new to Kotlin environment, please guide me.

**Foot Note:**

> I need to pass the values to Main.kt to activityTwo.kt so here i use ShardPref for handling the data. Above the values are not String type so i need to convert this to string values and pass to ActivityTwo.kt class. Important: ActivityTwo.kt file have a one method, it will support args types are ClassA,ClassB, and ClassC e.g for MyFunctionSample(ClassA,ClassB,ClassC) but i have a values in String Type so i need to convert the type to String to ClassA type. Here is i struck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to instantiate a class by name in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886266/is-there-a-way-to-instantiate-a-class-by-name-in-java).

Comment: @Tim Same error nothing works, i got thus error " Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Invalid name: com.crypto.wallet.data.AppDatabase_Impl@1056420"
i tried ths way 
" val kClass = Class.forName(appDatabase1)
  val object1 = kClass.newInstance() as AppDatabase"

Comment: You would need to use just the fully qualified class name, that is `com.crypto.wallet.data.AppDatabase_Impl`.

Comment: my fully qualtfied class path name is "com.crypto.wallet.data.AppDatabase" here where i can pass my string value for converting my string value to class type??

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish exactly?

Comment: @Roland I need to pass the values to Main.kt to activityTwo.kt so here i use ShardPref for handling the data.
Above the values are not String type so i need to convert this to string values and pass to ActivityTwo.kt class.

Important: ActivityTwo.kt file have a one method, it will support args types are ClassA,ClassB, and ClassC

e.g for

MyFunctionSample(ClassA,ClassB,ClassC)

but i have a values in String Type so i need to convert the type to String to ClassA type. Here is i struck.

Comment: Any one guide me plz

Comment: I don't understand what you're requirements are. It would be helpful if you could share information about what you're trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 0):

```
val str = "com.crypto.wallet.data.AppDatabase_Impl@14731a42"
```

For my common understanding to Java (yes, Java, not Kotlin), this implies:

- There is an interface or abstract class `com.crypto.wallet.data.AppDatabase`,
- There is a non-static non-abstract class `com.crypto.wallet.data.AppDatabase_Impl` which `implements` `com.crypto.wallet.data.AppDatabase`,
- There is an instance of `com.crypto.wallet.data.AppDatabase_Impl` that called something, with a "hashcode" `14731a42` (this hashcode is meaningless for most time).
- Neither this interface nor this implementation has `@Override` the `toString()` call.
- When called `toString()` on this "something" object, it *happens* to be `"com.crypto.wallet.data.AppDatabase_Impl@14731a42"`

This results to the `val str` mentioned in the original question.

There maybe some important content inside this instance, however it is **missing** if you call `toString()` directly.

To achieve your target, you should better implement a serializer and deserializer for your "AppDatabase" data structure, an easy way is to use JSON.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this:

```
val classType = Class.forName("packageName.class")
```

in your case

```
val classType = Class.forName("com.crypto.wallet.data.AppDatabase_Impl")
```

Comment: my class name is "com.crypto.wallet.data.AppDatabase'i tried this but not wkkroing i got error found Class<*> any but required Appdatabase