# Choose class to execute by giving classname in variable

Tags: java, class, reflection

I have let's say "Merge-Classes" that I call when I need to merge specific data with a specific JasperReport (Template). For each of those reports I need its own class to merge the data. I fill this reports dynamicaly, depending on which my custom wants.

Is it possible that I give my programm the name of the class and the method to call by a variable String and call that class/method?
So it would be easy to add new Merge-Classes to my program (only copy paste the file and call by given name)

For example: I have a main program and a class named Report.java with a same name class and the method Test()
in my main i have something like:

```
String classname = "Report.Test";
String parameters = "(var1, var2, var3)";

String end = """call class with params stored in classname+parameters"""
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to instantiate a class by name in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886266/is-there-a-way-to-instantiate-a-class-by-name-in-java) and [How do I invoke a Java method when given the method name as a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160970/how-do-i-invoke-a-java-method-when-given-the-method-name-as-a-string)

Comment: i added same "sample code", hope it helps

Comment: check the two linked posts, mix them and that should fit your need

Comment: Unclear what you're asking: is the `parameters` string literal or does it refer to named variables in scope? The latter is near-impossible to do in pure Java but may be a lot easier in a JavaScript interpreter (which is conveniently inluded in Java)

Comment: String parameters is just the second half of the class-call, you can also put the classname and the parameters in one String. I only wanted to show that everything should be flexible. Those are the tranfer parameters