# How to instantiate in Java a class given as a string

Tags: java, class, reflection, metaprogramming

I have a package with class files like this:

```
ClassA.java
ClassB.java
ClassC.java
...
App.java
```

App.java contains a main function which needs to instantiate an object depending on a given string  with a value "ClassX" matching one of the `CLass...java` classes.

How can I instantiate that class?

Comment: I assume you are familiar with conditional statements?

Comment: You chould check this post : https://stackoverflow.com/q/9886266/13237531

Comment: @Stultuske I probably didn't make it clear enough: I do not want to write conditionals for all the possible classes, but want to use the string value to instantiate the class.

Comment: @Vladimir That looks pretty good. Thanks! :-)