# How create many classes object in main class?

Tags: java, loops, class, object, oop

I have 50 classes. I need create 50 objects in main class for use these classes. Classes name Chapter1,Chapter2...Chapter50. How create create it just with loops in java?

I don't know. I have no idea. I cant find information about it in Net.

Comment: Or this? [Is there a way to instantiate a class by name in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9886266/328193)  There appear to be many duplicates if you search for how to create an instance of a class based on the string name of that class.

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions. The first solution, as already suggested in the comments, is to use **reflection**.

> Reflection is a feature in the Java programming language. It allows an
> executing Java program to examine or "introspect" upon itself, and
> manipulate the internal properties of the program. For example, it's
> possible for a Java class to obtain the names of all its members and
> display them.

Source: [oracle.com](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javareflection.html)

With reflection, you can create an instance of any class defined in a program by knowing its **full** name. The fully qualified name includes the package name and the class name, for example `package1.package2.ClassName`

**For this we can use this code:**

```java
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className);
Constructor<?> ctor = clazz.getConstructor();
Object object = ctor.newInstance();
```

To keep the example simple, I'm providing a code snippet that assumes that a parameterless constructor is available in all Chapter classes.

In addition, you need to save the created objects somewhere, and for these purposes you can use the `ArrayList<ClassType>` class.

Finally, care must be taken that all created objects have a common type. To do this, you can create an `IChapter` interface and implement it in each class Chapter-1 ... Chapter-n.

#### Implementation example:

File `IChapter`:

```java
public interface IChapter { }
```

Example of file `IChapter-n`:

```java
public class Chapter1 implements IChapter {
    public Chapter1() {
        //Some action
    }
}
```

Method `main`:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<IChapter> objects = new ArrayList<>(); //Create a list of IChapter objects
    int classQuantity = 3; //Specify the number of classes
    
    for (int i = 1; i <= classQuantity; ++i) {
        /* 
         * We specify the full name of the class with the package,
         * in my case I did not create a separate package.
         * The class number is taken from the loop
         */
        String fullClassName = "Chapter" + i;
        
        try {
            //Create an instance of the class
            Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(fullClassName);
            IChapter object = (IChapter) clazz.getConstructor().newInstance();

            //Adding the created object to the list
            objects.add(object);
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException
                | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException
                | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            //We catch possible errors and print them to the console
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    //Print to the console the names of all created objects from the list
    for (IChapter chapter : objects) System.out.println(chapter.getClass().getName());
}
```

In my case, the console output will be like this:

```
Chapter1
Chapter2
Chapter3
```

**As for the shortcomings, the most critical shortcoming is the speed of reflection. I would say that wherever you have to write an average amount of code without reflection and a few lines of code with reflection, you should choose the first option.**

It is possible to optimize this code to not create instances via reflection. This will require static initializers, but we still have to load the class. I don't know how much performance can be won this way, so if anyone has corrections, I'll be glad to hear in the comments.

#### Alternative Implementation Example:

Example of file `IChapter-n`:

```java
public class Chapter1 implements IChapter {
    //We create an instance in the static class initializer and add it to the Main class
    static {
        Main.registerObject(new Chapter1());
    }
}
```

Class `Main`:

```java
public class Main {
    private static List<IChapter> objects = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public static void registerObject(IChapter chapter) {
        objects.add(chapter);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int classQuantity = 3;
        
        for (int i = 1; i <= classQuantity; ++i) {
            String fullClassName = "Chapter" + i;
            
            try {
                //Load class
                Class.forName(fullClassName);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        
        for (IChapter chapter : objects) {
            System.out.println(chapter.getClass().getName());
        }
    }
}
```

#### Conclusion:

Having a class name and not having the desire to refer to this class directly, you can create a class using reflection, for example. But doing this is not recommended. Therefore, the most correct way would be to make a separate method that will create instances of the necessary classes. For example:

```java
public static void createObjects() {
    objects.add(new Chapter1());
    objects.add(new Chapter2());
    //ect...
}
```

Then you just need to call this method in the main method:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    createObjects();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create an array to store the 50 objects
        Object[] chapterObjects = new Object[50];
        
        // Create objects for each chapter using a loop
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            chapterObjects[i] = createChapterObject(i + 1);
        }
        
        // Use the objects as needed
        // ...
    }
    
    // Helper method to create an object for a specific chapter
    private static Object createChapterObject(int chapterNumber) {
        switch (chapterNumber) {
            case 1:
                return new Chapter1();
            case 2:
                return new Chapter2();
            // Add cases for all 50 chapters
            case 50:
                return new Chapter50();
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid chapter number: " + chapterNumber);
        }
    }
}
```

In this example, an array chapterObjects is created to store the 50 objects. The for loop is used to iterate from 1 to 50 and call the createChapterObject method to create an object for each chapter. The createChapterObject method takes the chapter number as an argument and uses a switch statement to return a new object for the corresponding class. Finally, the objects are stored in the chapterObjects array and can be used as needed.