# How to create object of a class where the class name is stored in string variable in C#

Tags: c#

I have a problem regarding creating a object of a class in c#  where a class name is stored in a string variable

eg. String str="Pilot"

```
As we create object of the class like this
ClassName objectname=new ClassName();
```

due to some reason instead of ClassName i need to use String Variable which stores my Class name.

Comment: have a look at this question: [How do I create an instance from a string in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648160/how-do-i-create-an-instance-from-a-string-in-c)

Comment: @Usre...what is the reason for this requirement?

Answer (score 2):

You would use [`Type.GetType(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx) and then [`Activator.CreateInstance(Type)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/wccyzw83.aspx):

```
Type type = Type.GetType(str);
object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Note:

- The type name must include the namespace, e.g. `Foo.Bar.SomeClassName`
- Unless you specify an assembly-qualified type name, `Type.GetType(string)` will only look in the currently executing assembly and `mscorlib`. If you want to use other assemblies, either use an assembly-qualified name or use [`Assembly.GetType(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/y0cd10tb.aspx) instead.
- This assumes there's a public parameterless constructor for the type
- Your variable type has to just be `instance`, as the type of a variable is part of what's needed at *compile* time

Comment: Jon, i think you answered this like 4 years ago: http://stackoverflow.com/a/648169/21567 :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example.  You will probably need to specify the full namespace path.

```
Namespace.Pilot config = (Namespace.Pilot)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("Namespace.Pilot"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to do so:

```
var type = Assembly.Load("MyAssembly").GetTypes().Where(t => t.Name.Equals(str));
return Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via usage of the `Activator`:

```
var type = "System.String";
var reallyAString = Activator.CreateInstance(
        // need a Type here, so get it by type name
        Type.GetType(type), 
        // string's has no parameterless ctor, so use the char array one
        new char[]{'a','b','c'});
Console.WriteLine(reallyAString);
Console.WriteLine(reallyAString.GetType().Name);
```

Output:

```
abc
String
```