# Elsa - dynamic activity called in .Then inside builder

Tags: c#, elsa-workflows

I want to add activity to builder with dynamic name.
I use

```
public void Build(IWorkflowBuilder builder) => builder
    .Then<FirstActivity>
    .Then<DinamicNameActivity>
```

FirstActivity is a class

I tried with https://stackoverflow.com/a/60107029/15352729 but I get  when i use

```
  .Then<GetClassFromString>() //GetClassFromString is like DinamicNameActivity
```

I get some errors. (className is setted inside GetClassFromString)

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to an activity using a dynamic name like this:

```cs
public void Build(IWorkflowBuilder builder) => builder
    .Then<FirstActivity>
    .Then("SomeDynamicallyTypeNamedActivity")
```

Which is useful when you for example implemented an activity provider that provides activity types based on something other than activity types implemented as C# classes.