# How do I instantiate a class given its string name?

Tags: c#, reflection, polymorphism

I have an abstract class and I want to initalize it to a class that extends it.

I have the child classes name as a string.

Besides this...

```
String childClassString;
MyAbstractClass myObject;

if (childClassString = "myExtenedObjectA")
    myObject = new ExtenedObjectA();
if (childClassString = "myExtenedObjectB")
    myObject = new ExtenedObjectB();
```

How can I do this? Basically how do I get rid of the if statements here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create an instance of a class from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223952/create-an-instance-of-a-class-from-a-string)

Answer (score 142, accepted):

Look at Activator.CreateInstance().

```
myObject = (MyAbstractClass)Activator.CreateInstance("AssemblyName", "TypeName");
```

or

```
var type = Type.GetType("MyFullyQualifiedTypeName");
var myObject = (MyAbstractClass)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. In case anybody has problems getting the fully qualified name, this piece of code is helpful '   string typex = typeof(classname).AssemblyQualifiedName;

Comment: Even though the `GetType` documentation for its `typeName` parameter says "The assembly-qualified name of the type", you don't actually need to include the assembly name. If the type is in the calling assembly, just the namespace-qualified type name is sufficient.

Answer (score 24):

I believe this should work:

```
myObject = (MyAbstractClass)Activator.CreateInstance(null, childClassString);
```

The `null` in the first parameter defaults to the current executing assembly. For more reference: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d133hta4.aspx)

edit: forgot to cast to `MyAbstractClass`

Answer (score 11):

I had some difficulty implementing some of the answers here because I was trying to instantiate an object from a different assembly (but in the same solution).  So I thought I'd post what I found to work.

First, the `Activator.CreateInstance` method has several overloads.  If you just call `Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("MyObj"))`, that assumes the object is defined in the current assembly, and it returns a `MyObj`.

If you call it as recommended in the answers here: `Activator.CreateInstance(string AssemblyName, string FullyQualifiedObjectName)`, then it instead returns an `ObjectHandle`, and you need to call `Unwrap()` on it to get your object.  This overload is useful when trying to call a method defined in a different assembly (BTW, you can use this overload in the current assembly, just leave the `AssemblyName` parameter null).

Now, I found that the suggestion above to use `typeof(ParentNamespace.ChildNamespace.MyObject).AssemblyQualifiedName`  for `AssemblyName` actually gave me errors, and I could not get that to work.  I'd get `System.IO.FileLoadException` (could not load file or assembly...).

What I did get to work is as follows:

```
var container = Activator.CreateInstance(@"AssemblyName",@"ParentNamespace.ChildNamespace.MyObject");
MyObject obj = (MyObject)container.Unwrap();
obj.DoStuff();
```