# Create an object whose type is in a string parameter

Tags: .net, vb.net, reflection

I have a TreeView, which contains nodes. When a user clicks on a node, corresponding CrystalReport document should be created and displayed.

For example, names of my nodes are: "PeriodReport1", "PeriodReport2", "PeriodReport3". My CrystalReport documents are named same: "PeriodReport1", "PeriodReport2", "PeriodReport3".

How can I create and display right type of crystal reports document? I could do something like this:

```
select case reportName
    case "PeriodReport1"
        dim myReport as new PeriodReport1
    case "PeriodReport2"
        dim myReport as new PeriodReport2
    ...
end select
```

But probably there is a nicer way to do this. Can I use reflection to do this?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247598/c-instantiate-class-from-string

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As long as the reports have a default paramaterless constructor, i.e. you can say new PeriodReport...

```
Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("namespace.typename"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
Type t = Type.GetType("object type name");
TBaseObj new_obj = (TBaseObj) Activator.CreateInstance(t);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also stash an object of any type in the `tag` property of the TreeNode, which is often useful for this sort of thing. It's not very MVC, but can be a good fit if you're not already trying to keep models and views separate (which WinForms doesn't encourage you to do)

Answer (score 0):

What about casting? How do I cast a 'Object' instance? Something like

```
string myCustomClassName = getMyCustomClassName();
var myCustomInstance = (???????)myGenericObject; //What do I replace ?????? with?
```