# java C# vb: how do we dynamically create an instance of a class from a string input (class name)

Tags: c#, java, vb.net, class, reflection

say i have this class **Framework.Asd.Human** with a public empty constructor. and i want to be able to dynamically create an instance of it from a string input "Framework.Asd.Human". Is this achievable? (in java and C#)

Edit:

Is it possible to pass in parameters too? like **new Framework.Asd.Human("John", 100, 200);** (i know there's no type safety but that's ok in this case)

Comment: See my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272679/create-an-object-whose-type-is-in-a-string-parameter

Comment: @_simon_ heys i've updated my question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this overload of the Activator.CreateInstance method:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcxyzt4d.aspx

Use it like this:

```
object myObject = (Framework.Asd.Human)Activator.CreateInstance(TypeOf(Framework.Asd.Human), new object[] { "John", 100, 200 });
```

And for Java: https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/references/java/java1.5/tutorial/reflect/object/arg.html

Answer (score 1):

---

Your going to want to look into reflection.

Check this out for c# and VB.Net - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx

For Java - http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/

EDIT

Since you asked about parameters....

c# - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx

Java - http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Language-Basics/ObjectReflectioninvokeconstructorwithparameters.htm

Comment: is java reflection capable of this too?

Comment: @pacifier I added a link to do the same in java.