# In C#, if the (string) class name is known, how to instantiate an object from that (string) class?

Tags: c#

In C#, how to instantiate an object against a class; but the class name is in a string variable?**

```
String stringNameOfClass = "SomeClass";
{stringNameOfClass} theObject = new {stringNameOfClass}();
```

In js, i think we could use eval()

```
var stringNameOfClass = "SomeClass";
eval('var theInstance = new ' + stringNameOfClass + '()');
theInstance.accessMethod();
```

**[EDIT]**
Given:
Classes name are unknown
But methods are known

I can get all classes name in a given folder.
Now I want to instantiate each of them accordingly by their namespace.
Though, I know the method i'm interested in.

```
arrayOfString = getAllClassesByNamespace('TheNamespace','/path');
// now call testMe() per instance
foreach (string str in arrayOfString )
{
{str} arrayOfString[str] = new {str};
str.testMe();
//in js
eval('var obj_' + arrayOfString[str] + ' = new ' + arrayOfString[str] + '()');
//if first class found is TheClass.. this is what I want to do
TheClass obj_TheClass = new TheClass();
obj_TheClass.testMe();
}
```

Comment: What are you _actually_ trying to do? In most cases questions regarding "cast string to class" are [XY problems](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and can often  be answered with: use a `Dictionary<string, SomeClass>` (instead of the obvious reflection approach).

Comment: I'm guessing you are after [`Activator.CreateInstance`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but it is important that C# probably has a better way of doing whatever you're trying to do. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: possible duplicate of [c# instantiate class from string](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2247598/50447)

Comment: the Class is unkown, so how am I going to do the declaration?

`UNKOWNclass theobject = UNKOWNClass();

var stringNameOfClassUNKNOWN = "SomeClass";
eval('var theInstance = new ' + stringNameOfClassUNKNOWN + '()');
theInstance.accessMethod();`

Comment: But *why* is it unknown? You obviously are expecting whatever class it is to have a method called `accessMethod` so if this is implemented in multiple classes perhaps it is just an interface that you need

Comment: Yes it is implemented in multiple classes, but these classes are test cases in unit test, we cannot assume what are their exact names. Ex. DefaultWidgetSizeTestCase, SimpleWidgetTestCase, anotherUnitTestCase etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the most straight forward solution I found in how to instantiate a class from string: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh.aspx

```
public class TestMethodInfo
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Get the constructor and create an instance of MagicClass

        String stringedClass = "MagicClass";
        String stringedClassMethod = "theMethod";
        Type magicType = Type.GetType(stringedClass);
        ConstructorInfo magicConstructor = magicType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
        object magicClassObject = magicConstructor.Invoke(new object[]{});

        // Get the ItsMagic method and invoke with a parameter value of 100

        MethodInfo magicMethod = magicType.GetMethod(stringedClassMethod);
        object magicValue = magicMethod.Invoke(magicClassObject, new object[]{100});

        Console.WriteLine("MethodInfo.Invoke() Example\n");
        Console.WriteLine("MagicClass.theMethod() returned: {0}", magicValue);
    }
}
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the Activator.CreateInstance method, this will take a number of parameters but there is one that will take a TypeName and Namespace allowing you to create an instance of a new class from it's name.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d133hta4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Hi, In my example I expect:
    TheClass obj_TheClass = new TheClass();
    obj_TheClass.testMe();

I believe Activator.CreateInstance needs a cast type, but as you see I have unkown, I can't TheObject = (Uknown)Activator.CreateInstance.....

Comment: Do all the class implement an interface or inherit from a base class? If so you can cast to that.  `MyBaseClass obj = (MyBaseClass)Activator.CreateInstance(...)`

Comment: Yes but, casting won't work since I would then have to access the derived classes methods, which i'm not sure if it is possible