# Call object from string

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [c# create an instance of a class from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223952/c-sharp-create-an-instance-of-a-class-from-a-string)

Hopefully this is pretty straightforward.

I'm looking to dynamically call an object based off a string representation of its name. Here is an example of what I'm looking to do:

```
public class Class1
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
    public string Property3 { get; set; }
}

public class Class2
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
    public string Property3 { get; set; }
}
```

My goal is to call `Class2` from a string representation (the `GetClassFromString()` is obviously made up, but hopefully describes what I'm looking to do):

```
Object cls = Object.GetClassFromString("Class2");
```

Then `cls` would be an object from `Class2`.

Comment: `if (str == "Class2") return new Class2();`?

Comment: DTB, that does seem practical. Thank you. However, if I am working with something that could be calling 40+ classes dynamically. I would like to avoid having to add a new if condition for every new class that might be added in the future. Would you have any suggestion on a more dynamic way of doing it?

Comment: @BenRecord: Check out the question I linked to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223952/c-sharp-create-an-instance-of-a-class-from-a-string  (yours is a duplicate of this one). That's a good solution, though a better solution is probably refactoring your application so you don't need reflection, unless you have some kind of exotic design.

Comment: `Activator.CreateInstance` is what you're looking for (though be careful, you'll have to use the fully qualified name o the class Class2 can exist in different namespaces and different assemblies loaded in the appdomain. That being said, I should warn that doing this is almost certainly a bad idea. I've written apps that were dynamic to high-heaven before without having even once to rely on this.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx) method.