# c# fill List with objects specified in call to function

Tags: c#

I have a class that loads data from my database. In this class, I have a function that actually loads the data and returns it to the calling function in the form of a DataTable.

I then iterate through the DataTable and create object of various classes based on each row.

What I would like to do, is change the flow so I can call the function that loads the data in a way that it can determine the type of object that should be created. Here are 2 psuedo calls to show the type of call I would like to make:

```
List<Teacher> =this.loadData(String sql, Hashtable data, {teachers class});
List<Student> = this.loadData(String sql, Hashtable data, {students class});
```

Right now the classes Teacher and Student don't extend a common class. However, if it helps, I can make a change like that.

lee

UPDATE:

Thanks to everyone who has given answers so far. It seems none of the solutions would actually improve the code I have or are beyond my programming skills.

I did find this post: [Create an instance of a class from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223952/c-sharp-create-an-instance-of-a-class-from-a-string)

In there someone mentions the following technique for creating a class from a string: System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CreateInstance(string className)

However, they also say that the resulting object has to be cast into the actual class. So it makes me wonder if I put the resulting class(before casting) into a List, will doing so automatically cast the object?

Answer (score 2):

Try wrapping your code that retrieves your database data into a class if you haven't. Then add two methods to return the specific type of object.

```
public class MyDataProvider
{
    bool isDataLoaded = false;

    public void LoadData(String sql, Hashtable data)
    {
        // Load data.
        isDataLoaded = true; // Or whatever mechanism you want to use to ensure data is loaded.
    }

    public IEnumerable<Student> GetStudents()
    {
        // Process student data if isDataLoaded.    
    }

    public IEnumerable<Teacher> GetTeachers()
    {
        // Process teacher data if isDataLoaded.
    }
}
```

And then use your Lists as you described.

```
MyDataProvider dp = new MyDataProvider("abc", data);

List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
students.AddRange(dp.GetStudents());

List<Teacher> teachers = new List<Teacher>();
teachers.AddRange(dp.GetTeachers());
```

Of course this is just one approach, but I think it will keep things a bit cleaner than what you described. You could also use generics, but you would need to provide a common interface for the Student and Teacher.

Answer (score 2):

Not that I'd recommend it, but to strictly answer the question, you could do the following:

```
public List<T> loadData<T>(String sql, Hashtable data)
{
    var type = typeof(T);

    if (type == typeof(Teacher))
    {
        // replace with code that builds Teacher list...
        return List<Teacher>() as List<T>;
    }
    else if (type == typeof(Student))
    {
        // replace with code that builds Student list...
        return List<Student>() as List<T>;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

To call it, do the following:

```
var teachers = loadData<Teacher>(sqlString, dataTable);
var students = loadData<Student>(sqlString, dataTable);
```

Of course, this approach has maintenance issues as the number of types grow.  There may be other approaches, but the one suggested by @Inisheer is a solid one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an enum to enumarate your classes and pass variable of this type to your function. But I think it is not good idea to have one function for loading all lists because if you have many classes to load you will end up with messy code.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to write a simple [ORM (Object Relational Mapping)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) component. Rather than implement it yourself, I would investigate [Microsoft's Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx) or [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/). These will load and save objects from a database with as much fine-grained control over the serialization as you need.

However, focusing on the problem you have, I would recommend splitting out the data loading to a separate class for each object, effectively the [repository pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx). That way, as classes are added or removed to your product, you are not focusing changes on a single class. The repository classes may share a common base class to avoid code duplication.