# How to create an object of class from his string name?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone

How to create an object of class from his string name in C#/NET in Windows Phone application?

For example in PHP:

```
$a = 'MainClass';
$b = new $a();
```

Can I do this in C#/.NET for Windows Phone application?

Comment: [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx) is what you're looking for

Comment: This [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223952/c-sharp-create-an-instance-of-a-class-from-a-string) may have answered your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (providing MainClass has a default constructor):

```
  // Depending on where you call it, it may require full class name: "MyNameSpace.MainClass"
  var b = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("MainClass"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = (MyType)Activator.CreateInstance("MyTypeAssembly", "MyType"))
```

Comment: You don't have `MyType` - only it's name. Otherwise you can simply do `new MyType()`