# No parameterless constructor defined for this object when trying to retrieve my object C#

Tags: c#

I have this method that I want to use to return an Object that i have created by passing in the type name:

```
public object GetObjectType(object objectTypeName)
{
    Type objecType = objectTypeName.GetType();
    return Activator.CreateInstance(objecType);
}
```

When I do this:

```
var a =  GetObjectType("Person");
```

I get: `No parameterless constructor defined for this object.`

Im not too sure what this `CreateInstance` does so im flying blind here.
Do I need to add something to my class which looks like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Is that the entire `Person` class, exactly as you have defined it?

Comment: The error seems pretty clear, what constructors have been defined on `Person`?

Comment: You probably have a constructor with parameters, in which case the default parameterless constructor is not auto implemented.

Comment: There are no methods an I just used person as an example because my actual classes hold alot of properties

Comment: Well, there is a constructor there, either it is nonpublic, or it has parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I have solved the problem:

```
Type objectType = Type.GetType("MyProject.Models.Person", true);
Object objectTypeInstance = (Activator.CreateInstance(objectType));
```

I can now retrieve my objects

Answer (score 5):

In fact you are trying to create new instance of String type, which indeed does not have a parameterless contructor.

```
public object GetObjectType(object objectTypeName)
{
    Type objecType = objectTypeName.GetType(); // objecType is String here
    return Activator.CreateInstance(objecType); // creation of String fails
}
```

What you might really want to do is this:

```
public object GetObjectType(string objectTypeName)
{
    Type objecType = Type.GetType(objectTypeName);
    return Activator.CreateInstance(objecType);
}
```

Comment: `Type objecType = Type.GetType(objectTypeName);` gives null?

Comment: @MikeBarnes, that is a different story - you might need a fully qualified name (if in different namespace), or an assembly (if in different assembly). Check out [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223952/c-sharp-create-an-instance-of-a-class-from-a-string) for more options, something make me think that second answer migth be your best bet. At least now you have the error while creating the actual type you need.

Comment: @Andrei, your solution won't compile, because `Type.GetType(typeName)` needs a string as parameter, not an object.

Comment: @abto, you are right, sorry, missed that first time. Can you please make the edit again?

Answer (score 3):

Try to add a parameterless constructor:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name {get; set;}

    public Person() {} // Parameterless constructor
}
```

Comment: It might be worth noting *why* `Activator.CreateInstance` might need a parameterless constructor.

Comment: FYI - Just tested it, you don't need to explicitly have a parameterless constructor unless you *also* have a parameterized one. Having no constructor counts as having a paramless one.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your are trying to create  object without passing arguments to available parameterised constructor u have. Try this:

```
public object GetObjectType(object objectTypeName)
{
    Type objecType = objectTypeName.GetType();
    //ur code works fine if do not have parameterised constructor
    return Activator.CreateInstance(objecType,"(do not forget to pass arguments)");
}
```

Comment: This would lead to an instance of type `string` with "(do not forget to pass arguments)".