# How to create a new object using string's content as an object name

Tags: c#

I am trying to name a `Person` object with "objectName" as below but not succeeding, 
any help? How to do it?

```
string objectNameString = "objectName";
Person objectNameString = new Person();
```

I try to create a Person list from several user inputs, the names must be unique in list.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Why you don't use `objectName` from the start? I don't see any logic on this.

Comment: What is your goal? Do you want to set the name of the Person, or do you want to set the name of the variable (of Person)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223952/c-sharp-create-an-instance-of-a-class-from-a-string

Comment: you don't want to do that

Comment: You might be trying to assign a property in Person object instead?

Comment: You need to understand that a *variable* name isn't part of the *object*. Perhaps you just want a `Dictionary<string, Person>`?

Answer (score 0):

Following should create new instance of `Person` using string from `objectNameString`.

```
string objectNameString = "Person";

var person = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CreateInstance(objectNameString );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the value of the `objectNameString` variable, using a [`Dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`ExpandoObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is the closest you can get:

```
Dictionary<string, object> someObject = new Dictionary<string, object>();
someObject[objectNameString] = new Person();

Person p = (Person)someObject[objectNameString];
```

Or, if you only add `Person`s, the dictionary could look like `Dictionary<string, Person>`.

Comment: @user3821069: need more help?

Answer (score 0):

I think I get your question. You have a string (e.g. from user input). And you want to create an Person which has the variable name of the string mentioned before.

```
Dictionary<string, Person> someObject = new Dictionary<string, Person>();
string objectNameString = "objectName";
someObject[objectNameString] = new Person();
```

Comment: Hi, Yes you got it! I try to get it from user input. But what is that "someObject",where does it come from otherwise i understood the solution!