# Is it possible to dynamically choose a polymorphic class

Tags: c#, class, polymorphism

I am using Polymorphism to define different shape classes using a base shape class

```
public class Shape
{
}

class Circle : Shape
{
}

class Triangle : Shape
{
}
```

At runtime, I create an instance of the class depending on a variable "thisShape"

```
Shape myShape;
if (thisShape == "Circle") myShape = new Circle();
if (thisShape == "Triangle") myShape = new Triangle();
```

This works, but I feel there should be a way to avoid using multiple if's.

```
# Pseudo code
Shape myShape = new {thisShape}();
```

Is there a one line syntax to a dynamic instance?

Comment: possible duplicate of [c# create an instance of a class from a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223952/c-sharp-create-an-instance-of-a-class-from-a-string)

Comment: You should be using if, else if, else if - or a switch case.  Allowing one if to fall through to the next is inefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should encapsulate this into `SimpleShapeFactory`.

If you don't want to write `if` or `case`, you could create your own `Attribute` (let name it `ShapeNameAttribute`):

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = false)]
sealed class ShapeNameAttribute : Attribute
{
    #region Constructors

    public ShapeNameAttribute(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    #endregion // Constructors

    #region Properties

    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    #endregion // Properties
}
```

Then mark all your classes with this attribute:

```
[ShapeName("Shape")]
public class Shape
{
}

[ShapeName("Circle")]
class Circle : Shape
{
}

[ShapeName("Triangle")]
class Triangle : Shape
{
}
```

And create `SimpleShapeFactory` like this:

```
static class SimpleShapeFactory
{
    #region Private Members

    public static readonly Type[] _shapes = new Type[]
    {
        typeof(Shape),
        typeof(Circle),
        typeof(Triangle)
    };

    #endregion // Private Members

    #region Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates shape by it's name
    /// </summary>
    /// <param xmlName="name">Name of the shape</param>
    /// <returns>Created shape</returns>
    public static Shape Create(string name)
    {
        foreach(var shape in _shapes)
        {
            var attribute = (ShapeNameAttribute)shape.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ShapeNameAttribute), true)[0];

            if(attribute.Name == name)
            {
                return (Shape)Activator.CreateInstance(shape);
            }
        }

        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid name");
    }

    #endregion // Methods

}
```

If you don't want to define allowed types in `SimpleShapeFactory`, you could, of course, use reflection to determine their, but

#### Note: Always remember, using reflection may cause performance problems.

Comment: Nice and clean solution, which I would definitely recommend over mine - at least it mostly solves the security problem.

Comment: I would still stay clear from using reflection for this use case, though, and your solution still uses reflection.

Comment: I agree with you. Reflection can improve readability when there will be a lot of `Shape` classes. For just three classes I would prefer `switch/case` solution.

Comment: Obviously, this was just a trivial example to get my query across. The real life scenario involves executing different business rules depending who the customer is. This solution is a great foundation. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In theory there is, but I wouldn't recommend it: You can use reflection for that.

```
Type shapeType = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType(thisShape);
Shape myShape = (Shape)Activator.CreateInstance(shapeType);
```

EDIT:

This comes with a lot of problems, including performance and security concerns. 
There are much better ways to deal with such issues, such as the Abstract Factory design pattern.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it either - especially if "thisShape" is populated by user input.

Comment: It may not be a so bad idea if "thisShape" is only a keywork linked to the corresponding class (for example thanks to a configuration file).

Comment: Well, you can certainly work around security concerns. But it isn't easy to get right, so I would stay clear from it.

Comment: Agreed.  There are possibly scenarios where adding this complexity is necessary / warranted / whatever.  Doing it just to avoid having an if/else block (by the way a switch case might be prettier) - no.

Comment: Exactly. Reflection is a powerful tool, but with great power comes great responsibility ;-).