# How to change string as class object?

Tags: c#, asp.net, reflection

i'm having the class name as string format "MyClass",i want to create a object for that class where i am referring this class namespace in     dll.

my requirement is:

```
MyClass myClassObj=new MyClass();
```

all i am having is string name= "MyClass";

so, by using the string name is there anyway to convert string as class object??

I had tried giving 
    "using NotCurrentProject.Entities"

```
string selectItem="myString";
Type elementType = Type.GetType("NotCurrentProject.Entities." + selectedEntity + ");
object o = Activator.CreateInstance(elementType);
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're looking for `Reflection`

Comment: Yes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223952/c-sharp-create-an-instance-of-a-class-from-a-string

Comment: Yes I'm looking for Reflection, but all I am having is just a String format of Class name(of other dll), which I am referring in current project. if I want to use as class object I should get Type of object, so for me its showing null because I am using the class which I referred in dll not of same executable project. So can you please help me??