# Start an intent based on a string

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to get a class name based a string. For example

```
String activityName = "Activity";
Intent i  = new Intent(context, ...);
```

Some how convert the string to call the activity class like

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, Activity.class);
```

Comment: You should look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223952/create-an-instance-of-a-class-from-a-string

Comment: Hmm, is there something similar in Java?

Comment: see Intent#setComponent(ComponentName)

Comment: alternatively you can use implicit intents and create new Intent like this: `new Intent(action_string)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
String activityName ="com.project.net.Activity";// provide the class name with domain 
Intent i= new Intent( context, Class.forName(activityName));
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is very possible. First, you will have to use the full name of the `activity` instead of the the file name, such as `com.package.Activity`.

```
String className = "com.package.Activity";
```

Then you can create a `Class` using that name like so:

```
Class<?> myClass = Class.forName(className);
```

Simply create a new instance of this `Class` and cast it to an `Activity`.

```
Activity myActivity = (Activity) myClass.newInstance();
```