# How can I instantiate an object from a string containing its classname?

Tags: c#, string, object, instance, instantiation

I have the following qualified class name stored in a string:

```
string className="Project.LogicLayer.FunctionsLayer.Medic";
```

Now I need a new instance of the class from using that string.

I tried this but it always returns `null`:

```
Type t=Type.GetType(className);
object = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
```

Comment: how about `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CreateInstance(string className)`  ?

Comment: [Create an instance of a class from a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223952/create-an-instance-of-a-class-from-a-string)

Comment: Is the class in the same assembly as you are calling Activator.CreateInstance? and is variable t null or not null?

Comment: I used it, but it returns null too.

Comment: @JSON, probably you confused with `typeof`.

Comment: @Glen Thomas  HAHA!  It's been a way to long of day at work.  I was thinking classname.GetType().  Removing my comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d133hta4(v=vs.110).aspx) of `Activator.CreateInstance`

```
Activator.CreateInstance("MedicAssembly", "Project.LogicLayer.FunctionsLayer.Medic");
```

Comment: Thanks, now it works, I have based in your example. `Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFrom("C:\\Projec\\AppMedical\\packages\\BussinessLayer\\lib\\net451\\Buessinesslayer.dll");
       Type t = asm.GetType(Project.LogicLayer.FunctionsLayer.Medic);
       var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(t);`