# How can I map a Entity Framework full name to an actual Model in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, entity

I have a variable that contains the namespace and the name of a model like so

```
Project1.Areas.Test.Models.Team
```

Is it possible to map this string to the actual model?

I want to be able to use it to construct the following class

I basicly want to create a Model type from a string.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: Creating a class instance from a class name is [trivial](http://stackoverflow.com/q/223952/861716).