# Parse dynamic data where its type is a string

Tags: c#, types

I have a a sql table with 2 columns, excluding PK, etc

---

```
 DataType                  Value
 --------------------------------------
 System.String             Demo
 System.Int32              23
 System.Decimal            184,54
 System.DateTime           2018-04-25 08:57:27.6305273
```

How can I parse dynamically the value from the `Value` column, as the type specified in the `DataType` column. There can also be different data types: bool, double, etc (Always standard ones. No customs data type so I don't need to fetch assemblies etc)

Of course I can have a dumb solution like:

```
 object value;

 if (DataType == "System.String")
 {
     value = Convert.ToString(XXXX);
 }
```

is there a better generic approach to parse this dynamically?

EDIT:

What do you guys think of this? Is it an overkill ?

```
Type oType = Type.GetType("System.String");

using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(VALUE_IN_HERE)))
{
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOriginal.Begin);
    var dcs = new DataContractSerializer(oType);
    return dcs.ReadObject(stream);
}
```

Comment: Sure, don't store the type in a column but provide one column for each value-type, Then you can use `reader.GetString(..)`,`reader.GetInt32(..)`,`reader.GetDecimal(..)`, `reader.GetDateTime(..)`

Comment: create `Type` object by name https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223952/create-an-instance-of-a-class-from-a-string and execute `Convert.ChangeType` https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.convert.changetype?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Convert_ChangeType_System_Object_System_Type_

Comment: What type has the `Value`-column in the database at all?

Comment: @TimSchmelter: nvarchar both

Comment: Seams Hanselman has a nice solution: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TypeConvertersTheresNotEnoughTypeDescripterGetConverterInTheWorld.aspx

Comment: Even with the Typeconverter, you will have to build something, that decides, which one to convert to... but they are nice.

Answer (score 4):

Storing data types seems like an anti-pattern but you could do something like:

```
Type t = Type.GetType(DataType);
value = Convert.ChangeType(XXXX, t);
```

Comment: @Fabjan yes per OP's declaration of `value`.  `dynamic value = `... could be better, but I honestly think this is just a band-aid on a wounded code base.

Comment: Whoops, sorry the `value` is actually of type `object`, then it's a good answer

Answer (score 0):

First: Don't get the String output, use a datareader if possible, a Linq Mapping or EntityFramework to access the colums.

Second: You could do it with a Factory ... or some sort of in the lack of a better name.

```
Dictionary<String,Func<String,object>> factory
```

add your methods that create the type and return it to the dictionary

```
factory["System.String"] = (s) => s;
factory["System.Int32"] (i) => Int32.Parse(i);
```

make it, that you have the *type* and the *value* in two variables and just execute

```
object val = factory[type](value);
```

You still dont have the type info, but you could go one step further:

```
Dictionary<String, Action<String>> factory;
factory["System.Int32"] = i => DoSomethingGeneric(Int32.Parse(i));
factory["System.String"] = s => DoSomethingGeneric(s);

private void DoSomethingGeneric<T>(T value)
{
  at least you have a type here and can do something with it
}
```

Still not very useful, but you mentioned generic(s).If you are willing to handle the values independently you could use this approach:

```
Dictionary<String, Action<String>> factory;
factory["System.Int32"] = i => DoSomethingWithInt(Int32.Parse(i));
factory["System.String"] = s => DoSomethingWithStrings(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Type foo = typeof(data);
```

will return you the parsed type, even if you inherited `data` with type object.