# Is it possible to create an instance of a class with "new class" key words ? c#

Tags: c#

I have an array filled with the names if some classes in my program .

```
string[] arr= new string[] {"company", "pokemon", "parents"}
```

is it possible to create an instance of a class like this:

```
list.Add(new class( arr[0] { "sdfs", "sfds", 123} ))
```

Comment: What are `sdfs`, `sfds` and `123`?

Comment: Are you asking how to [instantiate a class given its name as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/223952/11683)?

Comment: these are examples of my fileds in the classes
for example:
class Pokemon with
name="sdfs";
type="sfds";
age=123;

Comment: The approach does not make sense to me, as the different classes like Company, Pokemon and Parents would probably require different values for their fields/properties/constructor arguments. If so, there is little benefit in stuffing those class names into an array, as you will need to know precisely which class type is arr[0], arr[1], arr[2] to be able to choose the correct kind of arguments when trying to create an object. And since you have to know what class type arr[0] is, you can just forego using the class names array and use the class name directly like `list.Add(new Company() {...})`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for *object initialisers*?

Assuming you have a class `Pokemon`:

```
class Pokemon {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

and a `List<Pokemon>` called `list`, you can do this:

```
list.Add(new Pokemon { Name = "sdfs", Type = "sfds", Age = 123 });
```