# Instantiate class from string name, then call generic method of the interface it inherits

Tags: c#

I have the following

```
public interface IImportProcess
{
    Task Process(int id);
}

public class Sally:IImportProcess
{
    public async Task Process(int id)
    {...}
}
public class Bob:IImportProcess
{
    public async Task Process(int id)
    {...}
}
```

say I have "Sally" in my db, and I want to instantiate an object `Sally` but i dont want a concrete object, I simply want to get the interface version of it so I can just call `.Process()` on it and it would call the `.Process()` of `Sally` because the string/class it was created from is `Sally`

Same would be if I pass "Bob" then it would instantiate based on `Bob` class

Assuming all these classes are in the same assembly so I can use reflection and if possible Activator so I can do the following

```
var cls = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CreateInstance("Sally") as IImportProcess;
await cls.Process(1);
```

`cls` seems to always return null when it should not be null

Comment: So what happens with your code? What is your question?

Comment: I am confused by this question because the title does not match the code example, which does not use generics at all.

Comment: @JohnWu added the question, reopen pls

Comment: You need to use the fully qualified name for the type, try `Your.Namespace.Sally`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223952/create-an-instance-of-a-class-from-a-string

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://dotnetfiddle.net/a2wOqG

Comment: As a side note: it's normally much better to use `typeof(SomeTypeWhichExistsInYourAssembly).Assembly` rather than one of the `Assembly.GetXXXAssembly()` methods. E.g. `typeof(IImportProcess).Assembly`. Although `Activator.CreateInstance` is probably even better here.

Comment: @canton7 I assume OP has the class in a different namespace which is why you can repro and they can't.

Comment: @DavidG You're probably right (I previously upvoted your comment saying that). I generally try and avoid making assumptions like that: if the OP posts code which doesn't repro, they can go away and make it more like their actual code until it does. At that point, they'll discover what the difference is, and learn a useful debugging skill.